# Use Laravel API pagination in AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, laravel-4, pagination

I am building a simple Laravel + AgnularJS application. Initially I have a users resource in Laravel and it sending back all the users from the index method. It is situated here on:

http://todoapi.rohanchhabra.in/users

Now, I have included pagination in Laravel which means that if you pass a `GET` variable with the request, the results will change accordingly. Example:

http://todoapi.rohanchhabra.in/users/?page=2

I have a route in my application where I can easily fetch the results using the simple `$http` service provided by Angular. But it only fetches the first 20 results because of the pagination. Now how do I make my Angular app fetch other results according to the page number I pass.

This is how my controller looks like.

```
testingControllers.controller('UsersController',function($scope, $http){
    $scope.page = "Users Page";
    $http.get('http://todoapi.rohanchhabra.in/users').success(function(data){
        $scope.users = data.data;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when pagination click send the clicked pagination number in to a scope function , and your function should be like

```
$scope.getPaginationData = function(clickedPage) {
    var url = 'http://todoapi.rohanchhabra.in/users?page='+clickedPage;
    $scope.page = "Users Page";
    $http.get(url).success(function(data){
        $scope.users = data.data;
    });
}
```

your pagination something like, when clicking a pagination it will call the `getPaginationData()` function in the controller with the clicked page number as a parameter.

```
<span class="pagination" ng-click="getPaginationData(1)">1</span>
<span class="pagination" ng-click="getPaginationData(2)">2</span>
<span class="pagination" ng-click="getPaginationData(3)">3</span>
```